# How to connect a headless pi zero W running kali to home wifi?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Pi zero W and I am using [pi-tail](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-arm) as my OS of choice for the pi. I used rpi-imager to mount the img file onto the sd card. I added the wifi settings from the rpi-imager but for some reason it is not connecting. I also tried to manually add the connection file in the path `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` but still it is not connecting.

```
[connection]
id=<MyAP>
uuid=9c1b7640-8a52-40d3-a3fb-22e94b02cab0
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=<MyAP>

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=<MyPSK>

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto

[proxy]
```

How can I connect to the pi without using a monitor?

Comment: "_for some reason it is not connecting_" log messages? Any other feedback?

Comment: @roaima what logs, can you name the files or the path?

Comment: Either `journalctl` or else look for recently modified files under the `/var/log` directory